# Why I cannot create threads more than 32 by using tbb::task_scheduler_init?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, tbb

I tried to use task_scheduler_init to control the number of threads in my program. However, it seem that no matter how many threads I set, the maximum number of threads is 32. I use i7 and it has 8 logic cores.
For example, I set task_scheduler_init like this.

```
tbb::task_scheduler_init init(100);
```

In fact the number of threads is 32. I tried to use limited_arena to break the limitation, but failed. 
[image]

Comment: How many cores do you have on your machine?  Just curious if this affects it.

Comment: I use i7 and it has 8 logic cores. I don't know the relationship between 8 and 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hard limit for the TBB task scheduler. The idea is that the task scheduler is for a computational parallelism. There is no reason to increase the number of threads much higher than the number of hardware threads if you are actively computing something. It leads to over-subscription overheads, when the OS start to switch thread contexts too often.

TBB task scheduler is not designed for support of threads which block in the OS (e.g. for I/O). If you want to use TBB along with I/O tasks, please make sure to use asynchronous I/O instead. However, TBB recognizes that application designs are rarely perfect and thus allows this 4x over-subscription. Another way around is to create and manage your own thread using `std::thread` (TBB provides its own wrapper for old compilers in `"tbb/compat/thread"` header).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that by using this head file could help to break the limitation.

```
#define TBB_PREVIEW_GLOBAL_CONTROL 1
#include <tbb/global_control.h>
tbb::global_control MAXTHREADS(tbb::global_control::max_allowed_parallelism, aMaximumNumberOfThreads);//put it in a code block.
```

However, I am not sure if it is indeed useful or precise enough. Because when I use the intel vTune to run hotspot profiler. The threads counts is different from what I set when I set a relevent big number of thread, such as 100;